# MySQL order by multiple columns (id and integer)

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is structured as per the id (101, 102, 201, 301, etc.) with the first digit a navigational column, and with a placement value (1, 2, 3, and up) for knowing where the items in the navigation goes.

Here is how the table is structured in hind sight:

```
id   title   placement
101   abc      3
102   def      1
103   ghi      2
201   jkl      2
202   mno      3
203   pqr      1
301   stu      2
302   vwx      1
```

How I would like the table structured is the following:

```
id   title   placement
102   def      1    
103   ghi      2
101   abc      3
203   pqr      1
201   jkl      2
202   mno      3
302   vwx      1
301   stu      2
```

Notice how the placement is asc first,followed by the id.

I thought at first it would be a simple order by id, placement; But it's not.

I've tried both combinations of Group By and Order By, followed by a Union and a Field set value, but none worked to my knowledge.

Here is some querys I went through with no luck getting what I want:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY placement) t GROUP BY t.id
```

and

```
(SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY placement)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id);
```

I also did a join but I can't remember the query.

Thanks for any additional help.

Comment: How exactly do you want it sorted ? Do you want navid, then placement, then id ? just use SELECT * from table_name ORDER BY navid, placement,id (BTW, in your data you do not have any ties by only navid,placement ...)

Comment: navid is irrelevant since the id does the work, but in my project, I do have to go navid by number. I'll remove it for clearer purposes anyhow. What I'd like is ordered by placement then id, but it did not work very well for me. It had the placement values in order, but the ids were not. Hope I am clear enough.

Comment: Yes, and it worked. ID is an int(5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to order by the first digit of id first, then placement:

```
SELECT *, (id DIV 100) AS id_first_digit FROM t ORDER BY id_first_digit, placement;
```

You probably want to modify the expression for `id_first_digit` depending on your id format (e.g. if it can be four digits).